# How to pass a Date object as a parameter in routerLink in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes

This is my code block.In here i am trying to get checkinFrom date object as a parameter in routerLink to another component.

```
<app-chart-chip [routerLink]="['/statistics/subsegment',currentPS,checkinFrom]"
                                   [currentPS]="currentPS" [fromDate]="checkinFrom">
            </app-chart-chip>
```

This is my parent component code.

```
 currentPS: string;
    checkinFrom = new Date(2019, 8, 1);
    ngOnInit() {
     this.currentPS = 'PS';
    
    }
```

This is child component code

```
export class ChartChipComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
     @Input() fromDate = new Date();
     @Input() currentPS: string;
}
```

This is app.routing.module.ts file

```
{
    path: 'statistics/subsegment/:currentPS/:fromDate',
    component: StatisticsComponent,
    loadChildren: 'src/app/statistics/statistics.module#StatisticsModule',
    data: {
      title: 'Subsegmentation'
    }
  }
```

To this component i am trying to get date as parameter in routerLink in URL

```
export class StatisticsComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getParticularId();
}
getParticularId() {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    console.log(params);
}
}
```

But it's redirecting to dashboard.

```
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in the app chart chip

`[queryParams]="{date:checkinFrom }"`

```
<app-chart-chip [routerLink]="['/statistics/subsegment',currentPS,checkinFrom]"
     [queryParams]="{date:checkinFrom }"                              [currentPS]="currentPS" [fromDate]="checkinFrom">
            </app-chart-chip>
```

You can get the date like this

```
new URLSearchParams(new URL('http://localhost:4400/dashboard?date=Sun%20Sep%2001%202019%2000:00:00%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time').search).get('date');
```

Output
`"Sun Sep 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time"`

Comment: Then it will direct to a url like this [link] http://localhost:4400/dashboard?date=Sun%20Sep%2001%202019%2000:00:00%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time

Comment: Actually it's directing to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing the date is fine but I think the routerLink is just wrong.

Try this out:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params)
  })
```

HTML:

```
  [routerLink]="['/', 'statistics', 'subsegment', currentPS,checkinFrom]"
```

Comment: But i could get `currentPS`  value in this way.Only date i could n't get

Comment: What is param printing?

Comment: only these are params currentPS,checkinFrom

Comment: I know but what is it actually printing and I would use paramMap instead of param

Comment: When first reload the parent component html it will print in `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(this.currentPS);
    console.log(this.fromDate);
  }` in child component

Comment: todays date as i use  `@Input() fromDate = new Date();`

Comment: You are mixing things up. When you click on ChartChipComponent, it should open StatisticsComponent and print your url parameters. it doesnt have anything to do with the input and the ngOnChanges

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[routerLink]="['/consultation/calendar/']"
[queryParams]="{ date: lastAppointment?.startDate }"
```

And then:

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParams['date']
```